# Using Swipe View without tabs to switch to WebView using RecyclerView and Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, webview, firebase-realtime-database

I have build an application regarding to news, in which there will be different posts within `RecyclerView`. If a user swipe left on the post, it will take them to `WebView` of that post in which all the explained news of that post is shown. But the problem is that I could not make it happen.

I have implemented a post layout with `RecyclerView` and it is working fine. But I cant make the Swipe View so that it can take me to WebView page and also load the related webpage in it.

I am using Firebase as a Database. I have researched many questions but none of them worked for me.please help.

I am using Android Studio.

WebView class with FirebaseRecycler Adapter:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview_page);
        webVieRes = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycleWeb);
        mdataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("web");
        webviewthis = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_news);
        webviewthis.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webviewthis.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webviewthis.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post,postViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapte = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post,postViewHolder>(

                post.class,
                R.layout.web_card,
                postViewHolder.class,
                mdataRef
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(postViewHolder viewHolder, post model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setWebViewPost(model.getWebViewPost());
            }
        };
        webVieRes.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapte);
    }

    public static class postViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public postViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setWebViewPost(String webViewPost) {
            WebView post_web = (WebView) mView.findViewById(R.id.webView_news);
            post_web.loadUrl(webViewPost);
        }
    }
```

**Post class with Firebase Adapter**

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <post, postViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post, postViewHolder>(

        post.class,
        R.layout.post_row_recycle_home,
        postViewHolder.class,
        mDatabaseReference
) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(postViewHolder viewHolder, post model, int position) {
        viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
        viewHolder.setsource(model.getSource());
    }
};
mrecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


}

public static class postViewHolder extends RecyclerViewPager.ViewHolder{

View mView;

public postViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    mView = itemView;
}

public void setTitle(String title){
    TextView post_title = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.title_cardView);
    post_title.setText(title);
}
public void setsource(String source){
    TextView post_source = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.source_cardView);
    post_source.setText(source);
}
```

I want to have a swipe effect like this:-

[image]